# Form submission causing 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've created a form that is used to review a person on a website, however when the form is submitted nothing happens and console is showing a 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded'. Hopefully someone can help point out the error in my code stopping this from working. Here is the form code:

```
 <form id="fReviewMe" method="post" action="/process/review-p.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
    <label style="padding-top:10px"><i class="fa fa-asterisk magenta"></i> Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="span8" placeholder="Please tell us your name">
    <label><i class="fa fa-asterisk magenta"></i> Your Business Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="business" id="business" class="span8" placeholder="Please tell us your business name">
    <label><i class="fa fa-asterisk magenta"></i> Your Review:</label>
    <textarea name="reviewmsg" id="reviewmsg" class="span8" rows="8" placeholder="Please add your review in here"></textarea>
    <!--- form errors --->
            <div id="dFormErrors" class="row" style="display:none;padding-bottom:20px;">
              <span id="sEMessage" class="pull-right"></span>
              <i class="fa fa-asterisk magenta pull-right"></i>
            </div>
                                        
   <!--- form buttons --->
  <div id="dButtonsReviewForm" class="row">
      <a onClick="checkForm()" name="submit" class="cta pull-right">Submit</a>
      <a href="javascript:hideReviewMe()" class="pull-right cta" style="margin-right:6px">Cancel</a>
   </div>
  <!--- form saving --->
      <div id="dSavingReviewForm" style="display:none">
          <span class="pull-right hibuBtn" style="cursor:wait"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Saving</span>
      </div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
/* intercept submit event */
$( "#fReviewMe" ).submit(function(event) {
  checkForm();
  event.preventDefault();
});

/* form validation */
function checkForm(){
  var errors = 0;
  var cuname = $('#uname').val();
  var ccompany = $('#business').val()
  var creview = $('#reviewmsg').val()
  var cstars = $('#rStar').val()
  var eMessage = "";
  $('#dFormErrors').hide();
  $('input').removeClass('validFalse');
  $('textarea').removeClass('validFalse');

  if ($('#tnc').is(':checked')) {
  }
  else{
    eMessage = "Please tick to accepts out terms and conditions";
    errors++;   
  }

  if(cstars.length < 1){
    $("input").blur();
    $("textarea").blur();
    eMessage = "Please choose a star rating";
    errors++;
  }

  if(creview.length < 1){
    $('#reviewmsg').focus();
    $('#reviewmsg').addClass('validFalse');
    eMessage = "Please add your review";
    errors++;
  }
  else{
    $('#reviewmsg').addClass('validTrue');
  }

  if(ccompany.length < 1){
    $('#business').focus();
    $('#business').addClass('validFalse');
    eMessage = "Please tell us your business name";
    errors++;
  }
  else{
    $('#business').addClass('validTrue');
  }

  if(cuname.length < 1){
    $('#uname').focus();
    $('#uname').addClass('validFalse');
    eMessage = "Please tell us your name";
    errors++;
  }
  else{
    $('#uname').addClass('validTrue');
  }

  /* check errors and submit */
  if(errors > 0){
    $('#dFormErrors').slideDown();
    $('#sEMessage').html(eMessage)
  }
  else{
    $('#dButtonsReviewForm').hide();
    $('#dSavingReviewForm').show();
    $('#fReviewMe').submit();
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Replace `$('#fReviewMe').submit();` with:

```
$('#fReviewMe')[0].submit();
```

calling DOM node method `submit` to avoid submit jQuery handler 'loop'.

Comment: @A. Wolff Thanks for pointing out that there's other then click to submit, you gave me a lesson. Deleted my answer as it didn't consider all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks this helped me on the issue. So if I understand you correctly there is a Difference in the call of Dom Node.submit() and JQuerySelectedElement.submit() ? I had the expectation that if I select an element in Jquery the corresponding Dom function would be called, if it exists. So thats not the case.

Share

Comment: another one on jquery validation would be 
submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
}
and not $(form).submit();