# How to submit form after validating data not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am attempting to open a dialog, that has a form, and i want to be able to check the data on this form. Once the data is validated then i want to submit it. I do not have php downloaded locally, so i added the alert box, but when i submit it nothing happens. The dialog doesn't close.

I am new so from my understanding that when i query the `$('#dialog-form form')` I should be able to apply the submit function.

EDIT:Changed the form action to action="javascript:alert('Success!')". I think the problem is in the jquery `$("#dialog-form form").submit();` . The form doesnt submit which doesnt allow it to close after valid data was submitted.

```js
function addUser() {
  var valid=true;
  if ( valid ) {
   $("#dialog-form form").submit(); 
   $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        return valid;
}
dialog=$("#dialog-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  height: 500,
  width: 400,
  title: "title",
  modal:true,
  open: function() {
          $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
      },
  buttons: {
   "Sign up": addUser,
   Cancel: function(){
    dialog.dialog("close");
   }
  },
  close: function() {
   form[ 0 ].reset();
         allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
   tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
   tips.text("text.");
  },
  show: { effect: "drop", direction: "up", duration: 800 }
  
 });
 form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addUser();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-form">
   <p class=""></p>

   <form action="javascript:alert('Success!')">
    <fieldset>
     <input type="text" id="fname">
     <input type="text" id="lname">
     <input type="text" id="eid">
     <input type="email" id="email">
     <input type="password" id="pwd">
     <input type="password" id="conf-pwd">
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: This problem can be solved visiting this link: [jQuery handler 'loop'.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379409/form-submission-causing-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

`action=` takes a URL as its value, not plain JavaScript.  Try changing it to:

```
<form action="javascript:alert('Success!')">
```

Comment: that doesnt help. After the data is validated i want that form submitted. The query statement doesnt appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer after playing around with the code. Try this:

```
function addUser() {
  var valid=true;
  if ( valid ) {
            $("#dialog-form form").submit(); 

            }

}
dialog=$("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 400,
        title: "title",
        modal:true,
        open: function() {
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
            },
       buttons: [{ 
          text: "Sign Up", 
          click: function() { 
            addUser();
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
       }],
        close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            tips.text("text.");
        },
        show: { effect: "drop", direction: "up", duration: 800 }

    });
```

Comment: I changed that. I think the problem is in the jquery statement and function submit()

Comment: doesnt work i opened the developer window and when i click the sign up for either or it throws a "maximum call stack size exceed"

Comment: Check your code and make sure there's only one submit call

Comment: Or try removing form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {   event.preventDefault();   addUser();  });

Comment: I think your code may be calling addUser() multiple times

Comment: i found the solution being caused by the Jquery handler loop applying <code>$("#dialog-form form")[0].submit();</code> fixed it

Comment: Awesome. If I helped you at all please upvote or mark as answered, I'm trying to increase my points.